# Organizing Python objects for retrieval

Tags: python

I have a `Club` class and a `Player` Class. The player class has an attribute `Fav.clubs` which will have unique club values. So the user is supposed to enter various club names. Based on the club names I must retrieve those club objects and establish the relationship that this particular player has this `Fav.clubs`.

The attribute `Fav.clubs` in `Player` class should store the names of `Club`. Now what I have to do is, take input from user about `Fav.clubs` (a list). After that traverse each element in the list and access the string name to find the corresponding club object and then store that object instance in `Player` class.

Comment: 1.  Run-on paragraph that's hard to parse.  2.  No actual question that I could find.  3.  Sounds like homework.  Please break this up so we can parse it.  Please ask a clear question.  Please label homework with the [homework] tag.

Comment: @gizgok: Wasn't aware of the run-on paragraph?  Wasn't aware there was no question?  Wasn't aware that you have to do your own homework?  This sounds harsh because it is.  Please do your own homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all clubs in a dictionary called `all_clubs`. The key should be the club-name and the value the club object itself. Then you can do `all_clubs[clubname]` to retrieve the club object for a given name.

The player might have an attribute `club_names` which is the list of the unique names you described and a property `clubs` which might look like this:

```
class Player(object):
    # ...

    @property
    def clubs(self):
        result = []
        for name in self.club_names:
            result.append(all_clubs.get(name))
        return result
```

Alternatively, it might also be a good idea to use a ORM tool like sqlalchemy and a simple file-based or in-memory sqlite database. Then you have the power of SQL and a extremely good relational mapping. But if you are new to Python, I wouldn't use something like that, because sqlalchemy is quite a complex topic and the mapping uses some python magic in the background, which you might not understand at the beginning. Therefore, I would suggest the first method.

Comment: The problem is I'm making UI.So in player class I'm asking the user to enter fav.clubs.I dunno how to make dictionary using raw_input,but know how to make a list.so I made a list and now I check club class for has_key....Now I want to retrieve this object
and store this object in player class in either a list or a dict

Comment: The method I've explained requires you to call in the UI method for adding new clubs where you ask the user to enter the club name (and all other details like location?, leader?, etc) `all_clubs[clubname] = club` after the club object has been created.

For the player itself, you only have to enter the value for club_names, which should be a list. You might use something like `raw_input().split(',')` to generate this list from the user input.

The connection of the two classes is done in the property. `Player.clubs` is a list containing all Club objects which are named in `Player.club_names`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict` to store a map between strings and instances of `Club`:

```
clubmap = {
  'basketball': Club("Basketball club"),
  'chess': Club("Chess club"),
}

someplayer.joinclub(clubmap['basketball'])
```

Comment: The problem is I'm making UI.So in player class I'm asking the user to enter fav.clubs.I dunno how to make dictionary using raw_input,but know how to make a list.so I made a list and now I check club class for has_key....Now I want to retrieve this object and store this object in player class in either a list or a dict